# Does SUBQUERY( ) used in NSPredicate not support all collection operators like @max,@min?

Tags: core-data, subquery, nspredicate

I modified an example CoreDataBooks from Apple's developer site and I added an attribute `num` which is an integer in entity `Book`.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:"SUBQUERY(book, $b, $b.author == self.author).@min.num == self.num"];
```

I use this `NSPredicate` to fetch books which it's element's num is the minimum in all same author's books, but I get this error:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported KVC function in
>   trailing keypath SUBQUERY(book, $b, $b.author == author), @min.num'

I would like to know if a subquery does not support `@max`, `@min` or there's something wrong with my predicate.

Comment: Any chance you found an answer to this question? I've found SUBQUERY works with collection operators when the expression on the collection is TRUEPREDICATE, but not when evaluating a custom expression like $b.author == self.author.

Answer (score 0):

SUBQUERY results should support all collection keypath operators, or at least the documentation suggests so.

The error message is seems to suggest that the predicate in your code has a comma in it. Is it just being modified by the framework?

"@min" returns a number. What is the ".num" key you are requesting from it? Some kind of custom property? Is it supported by NSNumber through a category? Otherwise I don't recognize it. You don't need to (and shouldn't try to) convert NSNumber objects into primitive C types or anything like that.

Have you tried something more like this:

"self.num == SUBQUERY(book, $b, $b.author == self.author).@min" ?